# Rails 3 - is possible to make IFs in a database query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, conditional-statements

I have a profile card of user that have registration in my forum.

```
Person.update_all({:name => params[:person][:name],
                   :sex => params[:person][:sex],
                   :age => params[:person][:age],
                   :avatar => params[:person][:avatar].original_filename, 
                   :city => params[:person][:city]}, 
                   {:id => params[:id]})
```

This is query for updating data in database. But here is a small problem - this will work only in a situation, if I the user send through form avatar (image). If not send avatar - that means the user already have uploaded avatar and the form send only **name, sex, age and city**. So in this case I'll get error in line **:avatar => params[:person][:avatar].original_filename,** -- and I would like to ask you for, if exist some elegant way, how to treat this moment.

I thought something like this:

```
if params[:person][:avatar]
 avatar = ':avatar => params[:person][:avatar].original_filename,'
end
Person.update_all({:name => params[:person][:name],
                   :sex => params[:person][:sex],
                   :age => params[:person][:age],
                   avatar 
                   :city => params[:person][:city]}, 
                   {:id => params[:id]})
```

But unfortunately, this doesn't work... How you're solving similar situation?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems, like your params[:person] keys are similar to your model fields. So why don't you just pass `params[:person]` to `update_all`?

Alternatively, you could create a hash `person`, initialize it the way you want and then pass it to `update_all`

```
person = { :name => params[:person][:name] ,
...
if params[:person][:avatar]
  person[:avatar] = params[:person][:avatar].original_filename
end

Person.update(params[:id], person)
```

I've changed `update_all` to `update`, because `update_all` is used to update all the records (that match the condition), while `update` find's the record by it's ID.

But again, it's a bad practice and you have to type a lot of unnecessary code.

One more thing. `update_all` makes a direct DB call, which doesn't involve validations, callbacks etc.
So, if you don't have some special reason for this, you'd better do something like this:

```
@person = Person.find params[:id]
@person.update_attributes params[:person]
```

I really think, you should check [this book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) out

**Updated once again :)**

You see, such things belong to your models, not controllers. You could define a setter in the model:

```
def avatar=(value)
  write_attribute(:avatar, value.original_filename)
end
```

Comment: No, I have 10 fileds in my model, but here I need to edit just these 5 fields, therefore I am using update_all.

Can you please be more concrete in the second part of your message?

Comment: Ok, I'll try it, thanks. But if I want solve this situation by the idea above, would it be possible?

Comment: I think, you're doing something wrong. If you use update_attributes, it will only update the fields that are provided in the hash. Answering to your second comment, yes. I think, it would be. I'll update my answer in a minute

Comment: On a side note, update_attributes will only update the exposed fields in your model. This prevents the client from trying to force through changes that are not allowed.

Comment: OK - now I remember, why I did the update with "update_all" -> because I don't know, how to get the name of uploaded images. THIS: params[:person][:avatar].original_filename will get me the real name of image (name_of_image.jpg), but only 'params[:person][:avatar]' gives me whole object about that image... and I need to store only name of image

Comment: @jaydel - ok, I understand to benefits of 'update_attributes', maybe I have only bad habits from PHP (there I did often something like 'update_all')

Comment: Thanks for your hel bassneck, but I am sorry, I thinking how to right to use that setter in my controller... I am newbie, so I don't know yet

Comment: You don't use it in your controller. Just put it in your Person model. After that, whenever you try to set the Person.avatar, it will call the setter automatically before assigning it. This way you can just use `update_attributes`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but problem is, that: if I select file and send it via form, so that file is not saved - but in terminal I see the file is sent - it's strange. If I used before 'update_all ' so it works. The name of setter must be the same as the name of column in table?

Comment: And one more note yet - if I don't select file for sending and the form is sent without file, I'll get an error 'undefined method `original_filename' for nil:NilClass' -- I've forgotten something important?

Comment: The code is very simple - http://pastebin.com/MpWywki9 (it's more clean to past code on patebin than here to 'chat'). Strange is, the image is sent, but is not save to table.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. I've checked the code and updated my answer.

Comment: @bassneck - thanks! Much more cleaner solution than mine in the first message!